# csv file data upload to mysql in codeigniter Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and Undefined variable: result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

Am uploading csv data to mysql database ,while uploading getting below errors, Please find my controller and library and view file
Controller is csv.php

```
<?php

class Csv extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('csv_model');
        $this->load->library('csvimport');
    }

    function index() {
        $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook();
        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    }

    function importcsv() {
        $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook();
        $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $config['max_size'] = 1000;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        // If upload failed, display error
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {

            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

            $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
        } else {

            $file_data = $this->upload->data();
            $file_path =  './uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

            if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
                $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);

                foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                    $insert_data = array(
                        'firstname'=>$row['firstname'],
                        'lastname'=>$row['lastname'],
                        'phone'=>$row['phone'],
                        'email'=>$row['email'],
                    );
                    $this->csv_model->insert_csv($insert_data);
                }
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
                redirect(base_url().'csv');
                //echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);
            } else 
                $data['error'] = "Error occured";
                $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
            }

        } 

}
/*END OF FILE*/
```

library file is csvimport.php added in libraries

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 


/**
 * CodeIgniter CSV Import Class
 *
 * This library will help import a CSV file into
 * an associative array.
 * 
 * This library treats the first row of a CSV file
 * as a column header row.
 * 
 *
 * @package         CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage      Libraries
 * @category        Libraries
 * @author          Brad Stinson
 */

class Csvimport {

    private $filepath = "";
    private $handle = "";
    private $column_headers = "";

   /**
     * Function that parses a CSV file and returns results
     * as an array.
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   filepath        string  Location of the CSV file
     * @param   column_headers  array   Alternate values that will be used for array keys instead of first line of CSV
     * @param   detect_line_endings  boolean  When true sets the php INI settings to allow script to detect line endings. Needed for CSV files created on Macs.
     * @return  array
     */
    public function get_array($filepath='', $column_headers='', $detect_line_endings=FALSE)
    {
        // If true, auto detect row endings
        if($detect_line_endings){
            ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", TRUE);
        }

        // If file exists, set filepath
        if(file_exists($filepath))
        {
            $this->_set_filepath($filepath);
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;            
        }

        // If column headers provided, set them
        $this->_set_column_headers($column_headers);

        // Open the CSV for reading
        $this->_get_handle();

        $row = 0;

        while (($data = fgetcsv($this->handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {   
            // If first row, parse for column_headers
            if($row == 0)
            {
                // If column_headers already provided, use them
                if($this->column_headers)
                {
                    foreach ($this->column_headers as $key => $value)
                    {
                        $column_headers[$key] = trim($value);
                    }
                }
                else // Parse first row for column_headers to use
                {
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
                    {
                        $column_headers[$key] = trim($value);
                    }                
                }          
            }
            else
            {
                $new_row = $row - 1; // needed so that the returned array starts at 0 instead of 1
                foreach($column_headers as $key => $value) // assumes there are as many columns as their are title columns
                {
                    $result[$new_row][$value] = trim($data[$key]);
                }
            }
            $row++;
        }

        $this->_close_csv();

        return $result;
    }

   /**
     * Sets the filepath of a given CSV file
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   filepath    string  Location of the CSV file
     * @return  void
     */
    private function _set_filepath($filepath)
    {
        $this->filepath = $filepath;
    }

   /**
     * Sets the alternate column headers that will be used when creating the array
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   column_headers  array   Alternate column_headers that will be used instead of first line of CSV
     * @return  void
     */
    private function _set_column_headers($column_headers='')
    {
        if(is_array($column_headers) && !empty($column_headers))
        {
            $this->column_headers = $column_headers;
        }
    }

   /**
     * Opens the CSV file for parsing
     *
     * @access  private
     * @return  void
     */
    private function _get_handle()
    {
        $this->handle = fopen($this->filepath, "r");
    }

   /**
     * Closes the CSV file when complete
     *
     * @access  private
     * @return  array
     */
    private function _close_csv()
    {
        fclose($this->handle);
    }    
}
```

csv_model.php is below

```
<?php

class Csv_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function get_addressbook() {     
        $query = $this->db->get('addressbook');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function insert_csv($data) {
        $this->db->insert('addressbook', $data);
    }
}
/*END OF FILE*/
```

view file is csvindex.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Adddress Book Project</title>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="brand" href="#">My Address book</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">    
             <br>

             <?php if (isset($error)): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('success') == TRUE): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <h2>CI Addressbook Import</h2>
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>csv/importcsv" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="userfile" ><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>

            <br><br>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                <caption>Address Book List</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php if ($addressbook == FALSE): ?>
                        <tr><td colspan="4">There are currently No Addresses</td></tr>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php foreach ($addressbook as $row): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <hr>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy;My Address Book</p>
            </footer>

        </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

when am trying to upload csv file am getting below errors, can any one please tell me where is the issue in my code, am trying last day onwards not getting result.Am downloaded code form this website please check..
[This is link](https://www.sourcecodester.com/php/6477/how-import-csv-data-codeigniter.html)

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: libraries/csvimport.php

Line Number: 85

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\niranjan\application\libraries\csvimport.php
Line: 85
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\niranjan\application\controllers\csv.php
Line: 41
Function: get_array

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\niranjan\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: in line 85 of your library it says: "assumes there are as many columns as their are title columns", maybe your CSV doesn't have title columns?

Comment: no in my csv having these title columns .. `firstname lastname    phone email
   `

Comment: please you can also  try this code , its not working. showing errors Please check ..  [link](https://www.sourcecodester.com/php/6477/how-import-csv-data-codeigniter.html)

Comment: ANy one is there please please reply me

Comment: finally i got this link correct code .. [Here Correct Code](https://makitweb.com/how-to-import-data-in-mysql-with-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

Update the library `csvimport.php` to:

```
public function get_array($filepath='', $column_headers=array(), $detect_line_endings=FALSE)
{
    ...
}
```

Change the type of `$column_headers` parameter to an empty array instead of an empty single valued variable. It works!